# Deploy AWS Amplify Web App to EC2 (Not Lambda)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I recently realised my NEXT JS project I deployed on AWS Amplify uses Lambda but I need to deploy it on EC2. Is this possible at all?
I'm new to this whole thing so excuse the ignorance but for certain reasons I need to use EC2?
Is that possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS EC2 is a service that provides all the compute, storage, and networking needs you may have for any application you want to develop. From its site:

> Amazon EC2 offers the broadest and deepest compute platform with a choice of processor, storage, networking, operating system, and purchase model.
> [Source](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/?ec2-whats-new.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&ec2-whats-new.sort-order=desc)

Basically, you can create any number of virtual machines, connected among themselves and to the Internet however you like; and use any data persistence strategy.

There are many things to unpack when using EC2, but to start, I would suggest that you learn how to set up an EC2 instance using the default `VPC` that comes with your account. Be sure to configure the instance to have a public IP so you can access it through the Internet. Once inside, you can deploy your application however you like and access it through your public IP.

Before moving on, trying to decide why you need your app to run on EC2, Lambda is a SaaS (Software as a Service) product, meaning that all of the service provider's infrastructures are managed. On the other hand, EC2 is an IaaS product (Infrastructure as a Service) which means that you have to handle most of the infrastructure.